# Can we use ILP here?

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

Is it possible to encode $y=0\implies G=0$ else $G=x$ by Integer Linear Programming where $x,y,G$ are integer variables?

The answer mentioned below gets to the point of taking absolute value of difference of two integers $a,b$. How do we get $|a-b|$ from ILP?

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is binary, $x$ is non-negative and you know upper bound for $x$, you can calculate this as:
$G = \min(y \cdot K, x)$
where $K$ is greater than the upper bound.

If you only know the upper bound for $|x|$ and $|y|$, you can generalize this solution using tricks similar to https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/10/17/ilp-part-9/ . You basically need to compare $y$ with zero and use conditional operator (which is just a multiplication).

If you don't know the upper bound then I don't know the solution.

Comment: How to find min?

Comment: It is described here: https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2015/09/19/ilp-part-5/

Comment: It is not clear there.

Comment: Which part is not clear?

Comment: The way to do m which is min there.

Comment: taking absolute value is unclear.

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Notation? Symbols?

Comment: the procedure..

Comment: I am not going to rewrite those blog posts here so you need to be specific. First, you need to be able to use logical operators which is explained in first part. Next, you can compare numbers. Having that you can specify constraints for absolute value. Finally, you can calculate maximum and minimum together. Which part of those is unclear?

Comment: It suffices to compute $|a-b|$ for both max and min. That part is unclear in the blog.

Comment: You don't know if $a$ is greater than $b$ but you do know that $M>m$ (because this is how you define them). You want to make sure that the distance between $M$ and $m$ is the same as the distance between $a$ and $b$ so you add $|a-b| = M - m$. If the distance is the same and $M>a$ and $M>b$ and $m<a$ and $m<b$ it must be that $M=\max(a, b)$ and $m=\min(a,b)$. So now you have $M$ and $m$ correctly defined, you know that $m$ is min, so you use it in further computations.

Comment: To define max and min the blog uses absolute value. Here to find absolute value you are using max and min and this cyclic definition is confusion.

Comment: No, the blog uses comparisons and boolean algebra to define absolute value. This is the final formula for $x = |a|$: $\left(x + a \stackrel{?}{=} 0\right) \vee \left(x - a \stackrel{?}{=} 0\right) = 1$.